# find all directories named node_modules without subdirectories named node_modules

Tags: grep, find

In my dev root directory I'd like to find all `node_modules` directories. The problem is that `node_modules` itself contains subdirectories named `node_modules`.
How can I find only the top `node_modules` folder?
I tried:

```
find -iname "node_modules" | grep -P 'node_modules.*(?!node_modules)'
```

But it doesn't filter the subdirectories.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to "prune" `node_modules` directories from the search once they have been found:

```
find . -name 'node_modules' -prune
```

Example:

```
$ mkdir foo/{a,a/b,a/b/c,}/node_modules/{a,a/b,a/b/c,}/node_modules/ -p; cd foo
$ find . -name 'node_modules'
./a/b/c/node_modules
./a/b/c/node_modules/a/b/c/node_modules
./a/b/c/node_modules/a/b/node_modules
./a/b/c/node_modules/a/node_modules
./a/b/c/node_modules/node_modules
./a/b/node_modules
./a/b/node_modules/a/b/c/node_modules
./a/b/node_modules/a/b/node_modules
./a/b/node_modules/a/node_modules
./a/b/node_modules/node_modules
./a/node_modules
./a/node_modules/a/b/c/node_modules
./a/node_modules/a/b/node_modules
./a/node_modules/a/node_modules
./a/node_modules/node_modules
./node_modules
./node_modules/a/b/c/node_modules
./node_modules/a/b/node_modules
./node_modules/a/node_modules
./node_modules/node_modules
$ find . -name 'node_modules' -prune
./a/b/c/node_modules
./a/b/node_modules
./a/node_modules
./node_modules
```